# Creating HTTP Server with API and listener for all API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing with problem about creating HTTP server which has API on his side and also is able to listen all calls and log it.
I want to create something like:
Hub - server responsible for handle my window services which will registered, also communication logging between hub and nodes.
Nodes - window services which working as Client, which executing some tasks and using Hub API are able to logging information about that.

I dont know it is possible to create HTTP server which include API and HTTPListener. I tried like that, but this wont work.

Example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var httpServer = new HttpServer();

        httpServer.Start(); //Listener using address - http://localhost:8080 the same as SelfHostServer

        Console.WriteLine("Starting HTTP listener...");

        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:8080/");

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "API Default", 
            "api/{controller}/{id}",
            new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        using (HttpSelfHostServer server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config))
        {
            server.OpenAsync().Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        while (Program._keepRunning) { }

        httpServer.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Exiting gracefully...");
    }
```

Im not sure Im going good way, maybe I should create a separate server to listen and a separate selfhost server for the API?
Can someone explain what should I do for achive this? Thanks

EDIT

I want to avoid this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you this simple working server template **(However it is better to use frameworks like asp net core instead of your approach)**:

```
public class Program
{
    public static HttpListener listener;
    public static string url = "http://localhost:8000/";
    public static int pageViews = 0;
    public static int requestCount = 0;
    public static string pageData =
        "<!DOCTYPE>" +
        "<html>" +
        "  <head>" +
        "    <title>HttpListener Example</title>" +
        "  </head>" +
        "  <body>" +
        "    <p>Page Views: {0}</p>" +
        "    <form method=\"post\" action=\"shutdown\">" +
        "      <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Shutdown\" {1}>" +
        "    </form>" +
        "  </body>" +
        "</html>";


    public static async Task HandleIncomingConnections()
    {
        bool runServer = true;

        while (runServer)
        {
            HttpListenerContext ctx = await listener.GetContextAsync();

            HttpListenerRequest req = ctx.Request;
            HttpListenerResponse resp = ctx.Response;

            // Print out some info about the request
            Console.WriteLine("Request #: {0}", ++requestCount);
            Console.WriteLine(req.Url.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(req.HttpMethod);
            Console.WriteLine(req.UserHostName);
            Console.WriteLine(req.UserAgent);
            Console.WriteLine();

            if ((req.HttpMethod == "POST") && (req.Url.AbsolutePath == "/shutdown"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Shutdown requested");
                runServer = false;
            }

            // Write the response info
            var disableSubmit = !runServer ? "disabled" : "";
            var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(pageData, pageViews, disableSubmit));
            resp.ContentType = "text/html";
            resp.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            resp.ContentLength64 = data.LongLength;

            await resp.OutputStream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            resp.Close();
        }
    }


    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add(url);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Listening for connections on {0}", url);

        var listenTask = HandleIncomingConnections();
        listenTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        listener.Close();
    }


}
```

Comment: IKomarovLeonid Thanks for your solution its helpfull, but its still problem for me, because you wrote code for HttpListener only, what about API like endpoints for register nodes etc? That API should be near HttpListener on this server?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for middleware - https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Selfthost API server and HttpListener server was not needed.
All my web api calls will be catch and I can log all communications:

```
app.Use(async (context) => func with logic for logging });
```